Why is my get method for HttpURLConnection returning 404 on some sites?
So, I'm using this method to get the web page as html and return it as json/text:
public static String get(String urlString, Map<String, String> headers) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String jsonString = null;
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);
        System.out.println(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (url != null) {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
            if (headers != null && !headers.isEmpty()) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            jsonString = sb.toString();
            if (DeviceUtils.isEmulator())
                System.out.println("JSON: " + jsonString);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonString;
}

But on some sites it gives me a 404 error without printing anything. Using the same site with either python requests.get or cURL gives me the html page. I honestly don't understand what is wrong since most sites work out of the box. The url I'm trying to get the website (not for scrape) is any lemmy site: lemmy.world, lemmy.today, etc...
I tried to use a get("https://lemmy.world", null); to get the html page but it gives me a 404 without String output while other sites give me html page

I think you need to break that function up in to its constituent parts. That way you will be able to more easily verify that each one does what you think it should.
In all honesty I don't think you stand much of a chance of getting a stranger on Stackoverflow to try to figure out what on earth all of that is doing or is supposed to do.

@IvanWooll the String contentType = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Content-Type"); part is there as testing, so I'm going to remove it. It's the fact it gives me 404 on some website the problem

I tried but the response code is 200 using your method.
Maybe your network is bad.
